# How to use tf.py_function for working with tf.string?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-transform

I have tensor with strings (tf.string) and I want to split this strings by regexp and make some preprocessing.

For example I have function

```py
py_split(x):
    x = x.lower()
    x = re.split(r"(http:\/\/)|(https:\/\/)|(\W)", x)
    return x
```

and I need to use it in tensorflow-transform graph for using with tf serving in future.

But TF does not allow me to work with tf.string's same as normal strings in python.

How can I solve my problem without making new TF op in C++?

P.S. I use TensorFlow 1.13

Answer (score 1):

Slightly tricky because TensorFlow (at least to my knowledge) doesn't have a regex split function.

If there is a character that you can be sure your input strings won't contain you could do a slightly messy workaround using `tf.strings.regex_replace()` and `tf.strings.split()`.  We first use `regex_replace` in order to replace the match with our special character then use `split` to split on the special character

For example, if we could be sure our input strings would never contain the char `|` then we could proceed as follows:

```py
def split(x):
  x = tf.strings.regex_replace(x, "(http:\/\/)|(https:\/\/)|(\W)", "|")
  return tf.strings.split(tf.expand_dims(x, 0), '|').values
```

so that, `split("http://www.bbc.co.uk")` say, gives us:

```
[b'', b'www', b'bbc', b'co', b'uk']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but result of this operation isn't same because re.split not remove delimiters. For example for string: "Hello, world" re.split return `["Hello", ",", " ", "world"]`